# nested json to columns in postgresdb using python psycopg

Tags: python, json, postgresql, nested, psycopg2

i have nested json and want to write the values into my postgres db using python. i tried different things like json_populate_recordset, but that doesnt work with nested json.
i need to write the key_01/2_a-d values in one table and later the key_01/2_e values in another.

i am using python 3.5 and postgresql 9.3

```
 {
  "main_id_key01": {
    "key_01_a": "str_value_01_a",
    "key_01_b": "str_value_01_b",
    "key_01_c": 1111,
    "key_01_d": 2222,
    "key_01_e": [
      {
        "key_01_e_01": "str_value_01_e_01",
        "key_01_e_02": 333,
        "key_01_e_03": 444
      }
    ]
  },
  "main_id_key02": {
    "key_02_a": "str_value_02_a",
    "key_02_b": "str_value_02_b",
    "key_02_c": 5555,
    "key_02_d": 6666,
    "key_02_e": [
      {
        "key_02_e_01": "str_value_02_e_01",
        "key_02_e_02": 7777,
        "key_02_e_03": 8888
      },
      {
        "key_02_e_04": "str_value_02_e_04",
        "key_02_e_05": 9999,
        "key_02_e_06": 1010
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Post valid json.

Comment: sorry, now it´s valid

Comment: Will you insert the integer values as text?

Comment: i would prefer integer values, but at the end it doesnt matter